# Using MATLAB to send multiple serial signals through the same port

Tags: matlab, serial-port, microcontroller, multiplexing, interfacing

I'd like to send multiple signals (4 inputs and outputs and 7 outputs) from my Laptop to a microcontroller. I'm thinking of using a USB to serial converter and multiplexing the data through the port. I'll need to write codes both in the laptop end and in the microcontroller to multiplex the data.

Eg: 
Tx of microcontroller:
1.Temperature sensor ADC output->Laptop
2.Voltage sensor to laptop
3.Current Sensor to Laptop
4.Photodiode current to Laptop

So I need to write a program in the microcontroller to send the data in this order. How can I accomplish this? **I was thinking of an infinite loop which sends the data with time delays in between.**

At the Rx pin of Microcontroller,

Seven bit sequences. Each bit sequence will be used to set the duty cycle of a PWM generated by the microcontroller.

I also need the same multiplexing or demultiplexing arrangement in the matlab end. Here too, I'm thinking of allotting some virtual 'channels' at different instants of time. **What kind of algorithm would I need?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you always send all the inputs/outputs at the same rate, you could simply pack them into 'packets', which always start with one or more bytes with a fixed value that form a 'packet header'. The only risk is that one of the bytes of the sensor data might have the same value as the start-byte at the moment you try to start receiving bytes and you are not yet synchronized. You can reduce this risk by making the header longer, or by choosing a start-byte that is illegal output for the sensors (typically OxFF or so).

The sending loop on the microcontroller is really easy (pseudocode):

```
while True:
    measure_sensors()
    serial.send(START_BYTE)
    serial.send(temperature)
    serial.send(voltage)
    serial.send(current)
    serial.send(photodiode)
end while
```

The receiving loop is a bit more tricky, since it needs to synchronize first:

```
while True:
    data = serial.receive()
    if data != START_BYTE:
        print 'not synced'
        continue #restart at top of while
    end if
    temperature = serial.receive()
    voltage = serial.receive()
    current = serial.receive()
    photodiode = serial.receive()
    do_stuff_with_measurements()
end while
```

This same scheme can be used for communication in both directions.